# SQL Having on columns not in SELECT

Tags: sql, group-by, having

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
userid   mac_address   count
```

The entries for one user could look like this:

```
57193   001122334455   42
57193   000C6ED211E6   15
57193   FFFFFFFFFFFF   2
```

I want to create a view that displays only those MAC's that are considered "commonly used" for this user. For example, I want to filter out the MAC's that are used <10% compared to the most used MAC-address for that user. Furthermore I want 1 row per user. This could easily be achieved with a GROUP BY, HAVING & GROUP_CONCAT:

```
SELECT userid, GROUP_CONCAT(mac_address SEPARATOR ',') AS macs, count
FROM mactable
GROUP BY userid
HAVING count*10 >= MAX(count)
```

And indeed, the result is as follows:

```
57193   001122334455,000C6ED211E6   42
```

However I really don't want the count-column in my view. But if I take it out of the SELECT statement, I get the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'count' in 'having clause'
```

Is there any way I can perform this operation without being forced to have a nasty count-column in my view? I know I can probably do it using inner queries, but I would like to avoid doing that for performance reasons.

Your help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As `HAVING` explicitly refers to the column names in the select list, it is not possible what you want.
However, you can use your select as a subselect to a select that returns only the rows you want to have.

```
SELECT a.userid, a.macs
FROM
(
    SELECT userid, GROUP_CONCAT(mac_address SEPARATOR ',') AS macs, count
    FROM mactable
    GROUP BY userid
    HAVING count*10 >= MAX(count)
) as a
```

**UPDATE:**
Because of a limitation of MySQL this is not possible, although it works in other DBMS like Oracle.
One solution would be to create a view for the subquery. Another solution seems cleaner:

```
CREATE VIEW YOUR_VIEW (userid, macs) AS
SELECT userid, GROUP_CONCAT(mac_address SEPARATOR ',') AS macs, count
FROM mactable
GROUP BY userid
HAVING count*10 >= MAX(count)
```

This will declare the view as returning only the columns `userid` and `macs` although the underlying `SELECT` statement returns more columns than those two.
Although I am not sure, whether the non-DBMS MySQL supports this or not...

Comment: I didn't know subselects could be used like that. Thanks a lot, just the answer I was looking for!

Comment: However, I ran into the following:

    #1349 - View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

Any ideas?

Comment: @Rapsey: No, because you never told us, what DBMS you are using.

Comment: My apologies. I am using MySQL 5.1.41

Comment: @Rapsey: See update. I added the alias based in the information provided in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html).

Comment: @Rapsey: This possibly still doesn't work in MySQL because of a limitation. You can work around this issue by creating a view with the part of the sub select and use this view in the main view. However, this seems like overkill just to remove an unwanted column...

Comment: Naming the subselect doesn't help in MySQL.
After trying your update I get the following:

    #1353 - View's SELECT and view's field list have different column counts

Creating a second view to select from the first view does work.